# Should we prefer white color scheme for mobile apps?

Tags: gui-design, mobile-application

I am a developer and I pushes designers to choose light scheme for apps especially if they are used outdoors. I find light schema designs more readable outdoors. Is there any design guidelines about it? Which color schema required based on userbase, etc.

Comment: I don't think there is a definitive answer for this question, but I'm intrigued if there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to Readability (outdoor / indoor) **what matters the most is Contrast** and not the specific color. For instance, Black color on Yellow creates the highest contrast.

---

## Psychology

[**Color influences up to 90 percent of the opinion people form**](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2017/02/5-psychology-rules-every-ux-designer-must-know/)

[image]

---

[**Color psychology and associations**](https://www.usertesting.com/blog/2014/12/02/color-ux-conversion-rates/)

> It’s a well-known fact that colors can provoke emotions. Here are some
>   emotions traditionally associated with colors:
>
> **Red:** Power, passion, appetite, love, danger
>
> **Orange:** Confidence, cheerfulness, friendliness
>
> **Yellow:** Youth, happiness, warmth, sun
>
> **Green:** Growth, money, healing, environment, envy
>
> **Blue:** Trust, peace, loyalty, masculinity, safety
>
> **Purple:** Royalty, mystery, spirituality, creativity
>
> **Brown:** Outdoors, food, conservatism, earth
>
> **Black:** Formality, luxury, sophistication, death
>
> **White:** Purity, simplicity, goodness, freshness

Also, think about the the amount of battery the color combination might consume while in outdoor use.

Answer (score 0):

**Go outside when the sun is shining bright and try different color schemes.** It is much easier and valid to do that instead of relying on someone else's research!

When mobile apps are used outside the color pales (not if the screen is OLED). Therefore, the color itself is not as important as the contrast for readability.

If you want higher readability **you need higher contrast** between your primary task elements (text, images, buttons) and the background.

Comment: Haha. I do go out and check. 
But as I mentioned earlier I am a developer and if there are some standards or study data then I can be more confident to push designers on this.

Comment: @yuenshi Well your observation is much more valid than other experiments which may not be testing exactly what you want, or made the test with outdated technology, etc. So my advice is to rely on your observations.